# 2 errors: The multi-part identifier "inserted.name" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger to update a contact's info in a repository when it's been changed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER contacts_f_tr
ON contacts_f
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  ---
  ---Update repository data
  ---
  IF UPDATE (mail)
    BEGIN
      UPDATE mails
      SET contact = inserted.name, mail = inserted.mail
      WHERE mails.idcontact IN (SELECT mail FROM deleted) AND mails.tablecontact = 2
    END
END
```

I'm quite new at this, and I got this errors:

```
The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.name" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.mail" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're missing the `FROM Inserted` in your `UPDATE` statement - try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER contacts_f_tr
ON contacts_f
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  ---
  ---Update repository data
  ---
  IF UPDATE (mail)
    BEGIN
      UPDATE mails
      SET contact = inserted.name, mail = inserted.mail
      FROM Inserted     <<==== add this line here!
      WHERE mails.idcontact IN (SELECT mail FROM deleted) AND mails.tablecontact = 2
    END
END
```

Also - once you include that pseudo table, you should somehow reference it / join it to something else....

**Update:** well, you might want to add some extra `WHERE` clause if you add the `Inserted` pseudo table into the equation - what that is exactly is wholly dependent on your requirements, which I don't know - but it could be something like

```
WHERE mails.idcontact IN (SELECT mail FROM deleted) 
  AND mails.tablecontact = 2
  AND mails.MailId = Inserted.MailId
```

or something like that (to avoid a cartesian product in your `UPDATE` statement).

Comment: Thanks, no more errors. but could you elaborate a little more on that last part about the pseudo table?

Comment: Ok, I will look into that.